# Syncing Google Calendar and phone alarms

Tags: calendar, notification, google-calendar, alarm-clock, google

Is there a good app that can sync phone alarms with Google calendar? Google alarms/notifications are passive and tend to get missed - would love an app that set off an alarm or phoned to alert to an upcoming meeting. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Am I assuming correctly you're talking about an Android app? And have you set "reminders" for those calendar items? If you don't set reminders, there are usually no alarms. Setting reminders hence would solve that without the need of additional software.